# Parse & Swift - Preventing simultaneous logins - Parse Installation Object when user uninstalls app from phone

Tags: swift, parse-platform, installation, token, device

In order to solve a lot of problems I was having, I decided to prevent simultaneous logins by a single user. When a User signs into Parse, I check to see if there is an existing Installation with a Bool (isUserLoggedIn) set to true. If there is, the user is given a prompt to please logout of my app on all other devices before continuing. Once they do, they will be able to login.

This all working correctly.

However, I realized a potential issue. If the user logs into my app, and then deletes my app from their phone (*before they logout)*, I never have the chance to set the Bool value in the Installation object to false. So, the user deletes the app, the Installation object (which contains their user objectId as well) still has the isUserLoggedIn Bool set to true.

When the user re-installs my app on their phone, and goes to login with their previously created account, my app won't let them login, because the prompt thinks that previous Installation is still logged in.

So, any ideas on how to solve this? I could solve it if I could get a persistent device ID, but apparently you can't do that anymore with iOS devices. Once my app is uninstalled, the device ID will change with the re-installation of my app.

I could also solve it, if Parse could delete the Installation object when the user uninstalls the app from their phone, but that doesn't seem possible either.

The last thing I thought of, was if there is a way to query installation objects with the users objectID, and for all of those returned, query the deviceToken for each device. Any deviceToken that is no longer valid, that must be the Installation object from the previous app installation, which I could then delete from Parse, solving my problem.

I'd really like to hear your ideas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Wain's suggestion from this question:
[Handling Login on Multiple Devices using Parse iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905911/handling-login-on-multiple-devices-using-parse-ios)

I changed how I was tracking multiple installs (using the User class instead of the Installation class)